# How to chain promises returned from Services in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, promise

According to best practices I have created a service for all different chunks of API call and call the file as api.js;

Here is one example.

```
api.service('Auth', function(Config, $http, $q, $state) {
 this.login = function(jsonToSend) {
            return $http.post(Config.apiurl + '/user/auth/login', jsonToSend)
                .then(function(response) {
                    return response.data;
                }, function(error) {
                    return $q.reject(error.data);
                });
        };

        // Api function for signing the user up
        this.signup = function(jsonToSend) {
            return $http.post(Config.apiurl + '/user/auth/signup', jsonToSend)
                .then(function(response) {
                    return response.data;
                }, function(response) {
                    return $q.reject(response.data);
                });
        };

});
```

Now in my loginController.js I inject this service with other services. Now what I want to is.

```
Auth.Login()
.User.getUser()
.User.getCart()
.Item.getProduct()
```

My kiddish attempt. I know it's wrong  but the community asks you to show what you did.

```
var q = $q.defer() //intialize
Auth.login().then(function(response){
//some manipulation and store stuff in data
$q.resolve(data);
  })
.then(function(data){

})
```

I want to chain them like this. I know the representation is wrong, but I hope you get the idea of what I am trying to do here.

I have another option of doing this via waterfall method of async.js/ underscore.js but I want to improve my knowledge on promises and hence would like to know if this approach is possible. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can to save the promises to vars like this:

```
var loginPromise = Auth.login();
var userPromise = User.getUser();
var chartPromise = User.getCart();
var productPromise = Item.getProduct();
```

Then you can wait for all promises to resolve and do something with the results like this:

```
$q.all([loginPromise, userPromise , chartPromise , productPromise]).then(function(data){
 /* You can Access each promise data with the index of the order you put them into $q.all(..
  * data[0], data[1], data[2], data[3]
  */
});
```